# Update PHP version to PHP 7.* on Palapa Web Server (PAW)

Tags: php, laravel-5, paw

Would it be possible to update the version of PHP to PHP 7.* on Palapa Web Server (PAW), and if so can someone point me in the right direction?  Currently the PHP version is 5.5.11 and I require a version >= 5.6.4 as I would like to do development using Laravel 5.4, and in the future Laravel 5.5.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: If you mean [this Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfanla.android.pws), it's a full package. I'm not even sure that you can compile the app from source and generate your own .apk file—I couldn't find any licensing information on the vendor's site, much less a link to the source code.

Comment: @Alvaro Gonzalez Yeah that's the app I'm refering to.